# python math domain error calculating third angle of a triangle

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code to calculate third side of the triangle when two sides and  an angle is given.The input of the angle should be in degrees but since the math.cos() takes the value in radians so we need to convert it.

```
import math
a = float(input("enter value for side 1:"))
b = float(input("enter value for side 2:"))
c = float(input("enter angle value in degrees:"))
e = math.radians(c)
g = (a * a) + (b * b)
d = math.sqrt(g - (2 * a * c * (math.cos(e))))
print("third side value", d)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/question3.py", line 7, in <module>
    d = math.sqrt( g - (2 * a * c * (math.cos(e))))
ValueError: math domain error
```

any rectifications?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong formula. The Rule of Cosines mandates 
`side_a^2 + side_b^2 - 2 * side_a * side_b * cos(angle)` where you have 
`side_a^2 + side_b^2 - 2 * side_a * angle_in_degrees * cos(angle_in_radians)`.

You are getting the error becuase `g - (2 * a * c * (math.cos(e)))` may be (and is) a negative number. `math.sqrt` accepts positive arguments only.